# Cannot extend a template in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a following template:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% load static %}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{% translate "login page" %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'taskmanager/style/authpages.css' %}">
</head>
<body>

{% block testblock %}
{% endblock testblock %}


    <form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}" class="main-form">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <label for="username">{% translate "User name: " %}</label>
        {{ form.username }}
        {{ form.username.errors }}

        <label for="password">{% translate "Password: " %} </label>
        {{ form.password }}
        {{ form.password.errors }}

        {% if form.errors %}
            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        {% endif %}

        <input type="submit" value="{% translate 'sign in' %}">
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">

        <a href="{% url 'register' %}">{% translate "Register" %}</a>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

and also I have a template to extend it:

```
{% extends "registration/login.html" %}

{% block testblock %}
    <div> testblock content </div>
{% endblock testblock %}
```

template settings in settings.py is standard and was not changed:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

It seems to me that everything I have done is consistent with the documentation and I cannot figure out which of these is not working. I honestly tried to figure out why, and searched for an answer here and on Google, but I failed. Help me please.

link to the GitHub [repository](https://github.com/ImHereByChance/MonthsWeb/tree/template_issue) if you need to see an entire project structure or [templates folder](https://github.com/ImHereByChance/MonthsWeb/tree/template_issue/MonthsWeb/taskmanager/templates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just forgot to change the template name in render() function of the appropriate view from `"registration/login.html"` to `"registration/test.html"`. It's silly, excuse for troubling.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your full settings.py but I think the problem is in there.  You need to add the actual directory.  Here is an example from one of my projects, just copy/paste over yours and it should fix it:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: according to documentation, DIRS is the list of folders with templates that located outside the templates folders of the apps. If APP_DIRS parameter is set to True, templates loader should search for templates inside each template folder of the each app, and since I store  my tampletes in the app_name/templates folder, the loader should see them. So DIRS parameter is for extending templates sources through the adding additional dirrectories. I tried to do it anyway and explicitly pointed to the app_name/templates dir but it changed nothing.

Comment: my [settings.py](https://github.com/ImHereByChance/MonthsWeb/blob/template_issue/MonthsWeb/MonthsWeb/settings.py) file